# Selenium webdriver (java) - Click on desired link of some search results

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automation using selenium webdriver (java) on a search engine BookMyCrop (http://www.bookmycrop.com). Here, I searched for a crop but, I am not able to click on desired search result. Please help me with it.

Code :

```
 WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_keyword\"]")); 
search.sendKeys("59825"); 
search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Cashew")).click(); 
------My 1st try------------- 
//WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("\"//div[@id = 'Links']/a[3]\"")); 
//link.click();

 ------My 2nd try------------- 

//List<WebElement> find = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/section[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]")); 
//find.get(1).click(); 
} 
} –
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? What have you tried so far ? Can we see your code ?

Comment: WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_keyword\"]"));
search.sendKeys("59825");
search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Cashew")).click();
------My 1st try-------------
//WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("\"//div[@id = 'Links']/a[3]\""));
//link.click();

------My 2nd try-------------  
//List<WebElement> find = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/section[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]"));
//find.get(1).click();   
}
}

Comment: Hello, the code you mentioned worked for me. I also post the full code I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css selector based on class names: ".product-block.inner-product-block" and get the list of all the search results.
Then click on whatever index you want to click.

I am not using an IDE for this but it would look something like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".product-block.inner-product-block")).get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, you can try with css ".product-block.inner-product-block"
Then

1. get List of WebElements
2. do loop
3. inside loop, try get text of each element or innerText attribute
4. cross check if it is required one or not by simple if condition
5. If so, click on that web element and break loop

if this locator is not giving required info, try other locator. say $$("a h3") for veg names.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me. It is navigates to the correct link

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.bookmycrop.com");
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_keyword\"]")); 
        search.sendKeys("59825"); 
        search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Cashew")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but till here, I have also done. I am having problem in clicking on any search result of Cashew.

Comment: Please explain again what is your requirement. Because the cashew link is successfully clicked by my code.

Comment: I have searched for "Cashew" and got search results like in google. In google you click on a desired search result from the list. Same thing is here. How to detect which search result I want to click? But, I have got a temporary kind of solution by detecting using cssselector and passing the index in get(). Thanks for your help.